# copying array into another and replacing missing field with null

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically generating array GeneratedReport as,

```
Generated[0]=[10];
Generated[1]=[1,5];
Generated[2]=[10,6,7];
```

from above array i need to create 1 New array FinalReport where i need 3 value from above above array  e.g Generated[0] should give 3 values if not then 2 missing values should be replaced with Null or zero.

FinalReport should be like,

```
finalReport=[10,0,0,1,5,0,10,6,7]
```

I tried below code and many thing but not working . please suggest,

**I know below code is not correct but just need to show you all efforts**

```
//iterating temp array
for(var i=0;i<GenerateReportSep.length;i++)
{

    var genLen=GenerateReportSep[i].length;
    //loop throgh each array
    for(var k=0;k<GenerateReportSep[i].length;k++)
    {


    //check lenth with 3 or what ever no. required in pdf
    if(genLen<3)
    {

         GenerateReport[seq]="NULL";
        genLen++;

        }
        else
        {
            //store value in 
         GenerateReport[seq]=GenerateReportSep[i][k];           
            }

    }//end of check each generatedsep[i] array
}

    }
```

Comment: Why the [tag:java] tag? How does your problem relate to Java programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution :

```
var finalReport = [];

for (i = 0; i < Generated.length; i++) {
    var currArr = Generated[i];
    var numZeros = 3 - currArr.length;
    for (j = 0; j < currArr.length; j++) {
        finalReport.push(currArr[j])
    }

    while (numZeros) {
        finalReport.push(0);
        numZeros--;
    }

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6X4Z/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, replace 0 with your default value:

```
var n, e, finalReport = [], tmp;
for ( n = 0, e = GenerateReportSep.length; n < e; n++ )
{
    tmp = GenerateReportSep[n];
    finalReport.push( tmp[0] || 0 );
    finalReport.push( tmp[1] || 0 );
    finalReport.push( tmp[2] || 0 );
}
```